# NEC 2SK3919 MOSFET replacement

Tags: mosfet

A few MOSFETS have failed on my motherboard.  And I was looking on the web to find a replacement for the ones that have died.  The ones that are currently on my motherboard are NEC 2SK3919. The only problem is I can not find any MOSFETS on Mouser.com ( or any site ) that had similar values to mine.

So I was wondering what values can be slightly higher/lower and what can not be changed.  I think that Vds and Vgs must be the same, but the td(on), td(off), QG, can be different, correct?

I know the motherboard is fairly old, its a HP Nettle2-GL8E, so some might say to replace the board, but I would like to learn MOSFETS and what happens to the DC current once it goes in the PSU.

Thank You!

Comment: The voltage, current, and watt rating should be higher to prevent damage. The resistance values should be very close to avoid overheating parts among other things.

Comment: @mcmiln the  NEC 2SK3919 has RDS(on)1 of 5.6 max at 32 A while the STMicroelectronics' STD95N2LH5 has a RDS(on)1 of 4.9 at 40 A.  How would I convert the STM result at 40 A to the NEC result of 32 to make it easier to see if the mΩ vaule is in the ballpark?  Or is the no point in converting the numbers because the NEC is 5.6 at 32 increasing it to 40 would increase the 5.6 higher showing that the two numbers are to far apart.   And if the two numbers are two far apart can I just put a fan over-top to limit the heat they will be producing?

Answer (score 1):

As to Vds and Vgs, those ratings should be the same or higher. As to the on and off times, those should be the same or faster. Gate charge or capacitance should be the same or smaller. ON resistance value should be the same or lower.

This MOSFET, like most, is also equipped with a body diode. That diode will have a reverse recovery time, and your replacement MOSFET must have a diode with a recovery time that is the same or smaller.

As an aside, for the most part, what this MOSFET is doing for the PSU is acting as the switch in a switching power supply or voltage regulator. Generically, these are used to regulate voltage and current to various components on the board.